# DB2 SQL Validation

Tags: c#, sql, db2

I am looking for something, where I can validate the DB2-SQL Text that I am receiving on Client end. I do not want to make a DB call just to validate SQL Text. Any parser available to validate DB2 SQL texts ? I am using C#.

Comment: I believe this is a lot more trouble than it's worth. Even if you do find an SQL parser fully compatible with DB2, you should probably run a bunch of tests against just querying the DB. I believe validating through the DB will be a lot faster, regardless (assuming your concern is performance). Besides, chances are your C# code will have no knowledge of schema, data in the DB, etc. to be of much use.

Comment: I will be checking it at the time of execution obviously. But when I am receiving 100s of Queries from another application, doesn't make sense hitting DB every time just to make sure its correct syntactically. Microsoft itself provides [TSql100Parser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.schema.scriptdom.sql.tsql100parser.aspx) in .net4 considering it useful to check syntax for Query. But than it is limited to SQL Server text.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to "prepare" the statement without executing it.

SQL parsers are truly difficult beasts to write and you will never get it 100% right, besides even if you can scan for correct syntax you have no idea what tables and views are currently defined in the target system.

So assuming its just "SELECT" statements you want to check just "PREPARE" them and check for errors, but, don't execute.